React Native Expo hide android navigation bar
enter image description here
I'm developing an app and I want users to not be able to exit the app via the Android navigation bar, what can I do?
In the app.json file, I'm putting the following:
enter image description here
When I'm in development using npx expo start, the navigation bar behaves as expected. But when I create an APK, the bar always remains visible.
To have the bar always hidden.

Instead of hiding, you can handle back press of navigation with the help of BackHandler which can be imported from react-native lib. You can check out https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler which is official doc. Hope it helps.

yes, but does this work for the back button, and the home button and recent app?
Is it possible to catch these events and not let the user leave?

It handles only back button
